# MySQL Database Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 1 7

Tags: mysql

Getting error in the below code can anybody help

```
INSERT INTO `qqreports`.FY15_Short_Form_Data(Quick_Quote_ID,Cc, Quote_Net_Total,Line_Item_Total,Currency_code,Item_No_1_Product_Description,Company_Name,Country_Name,Creation_Date_US_MT,Email_Address,Email_Domain_Name,Timeframe,Contact_Stat,Individual_Frequency_Indicator,Individual_Quote_Count,Product_ID,Region,Vendor_Name,Month,Year,PL,Disty_NonDisty )  SELECT  T1.Quick_Quote_ID,  T1.Cc,  T1.Quote_Net_Total,T1.Line_Item_Total,T1.Currency_Code,T1.Item_No_1_Product_Description,T1.Company_Name,T1.Country_Name,T1.Creation_Date_US_MT,T1.Email_AddressT1.Email_Domain_Name,T1.Timeframe,T1.Contact_Stat,T1.Individual_Frequency_Indicator,T1.Individual_Quote_Count,T1.Product_ID,T1.Region, T1.Vendor_Name,Month(T1.Creation_Date_US_MT) As 'Month',Year(T1.Creation_Date_US_MT) As 'Year' ,T2.Product_Line AS PL,T1.Line_Item_Total / T3.Units_1USD AS Value_In_USD,If(Left(T1.Quick_Quote_ID, 1) = '4', 'Disty', 'NonDisty') AS Disty_NonDisty FROM ngq_master AS T1 Left join abc_master AS T2 ON T1.Product_ID = T2.Item_No Left Join Currency_master T3ON T1.Currency_Code = T3.Code where Month(T1.Creation_Date_US_MT)=11 and Year(T1.Creation_Date_US_MT)=2016 order by T1.S_No;
```

Comment: First step towards fixing your problem: Fix the formatting of your question.  I doubt you even know what that one line statement is actually doing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if the formatting was fixed in the first place the error would reveal itself. :)

Comment: @PeterDarmis If it's just a simply typo, then don't answer, just vote to close.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have answered already one field name was missing and in the select statement two fields where forgotten without being separated by comma. I don't know if this is considered a typo,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try now you had error since `value_in_usd` was missing and a comma was also missing to separate two more fields in the `select` statement.

```
INSERT INTO `qqreports`.FY15_Short_Form_Data 
(Quick_Quote_ID,
Cc, 
Quote_Net_Total,
Line_Item_Total,
Currency_code,
Item_No_1_Product_Description,
Company_Name,
Country_Name,
Creation_Date_US_MT,
Email_Address,
Email_Domain_Name,
Timeframe,
Contact_Stat,
Individual_Frequency_Indicator,
Individual_Quote_Count,
Product_ID,
Region,
Vendor_Name,
Month,
Year,
PL,
Value_In_USD,
Disty_NonDisty )  
SELECT  T1.Quick_Quote_ID,  
T1.Cc,  
T1.Quote_Net_Total,
T1.Line_Item_Total,
T1.Currency_Code,
T1.Item_No_1_Product_Description,
T1.Company_Name,
T1.Country_Name,
T1.Creation_Date_US_MT,
T1.Email_Address,
T1.Email_Domain_Name,
T1.Timeframe,
T1.Contact_Stat,
T1.Individual_Frequency_Indicator,
T1.Individual_Quote_Count,
T1.Product_ID,
T1.Region, 
T1.Vendor_Name,
Month(T1.Creation_Date_US_MT) As 'Month',
Year(T1.Creation_Date_US_MT) As 'Year' ,
T2.Product_Line AS PL,
T1.Line_Item_Total / T3.Units_1USD AS Value_In_USD,
If(Left(T1.Quick_Quote_ID, 1) = '4', 'Disty', 'NonDisty') AS Disty_NonDisty 
FROM ngq_master AS T1 
Left join abc_master AS T2 ON T1.Product_ID = T2.Item_No 
Left Join Currency_master T3 ON T1.Currency_Code = T3.Code 
where Month(T1.Creation_Date_US_MT)=11 and Year(T1.Creation_Date_US_MT)=2016 
order by T1.S_No;
```

Comment: I give you a up vote for taking the time to format the SQL and hunt down the missing comma!

Answer (score 0):

The number of columns you are trying to INSERT and the DATA you have given doesn't match

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the number of values returned from your SELECT doesn't match the column list in the preceding INSERT.